# RID and Key lock on same object by a Select and Delete query

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock, extended-events, blocking

To be specific how did the select query (spid 128, on the left) is able to acquire a S (shared) lock on Index but not on the row?

Also, how did Delete query (SPID 121, on the right) is able to get X (exclusive) lock on object but unable to get a X lock on Index?

Deadlock XML:

```xml
<deadlock>
 <victim-list>
  <victimProcess id="processa4c4804e8" />
 </victim-list>
 <process-list>
  <process id="processa4c4804e8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="RID: 19:1:6635214:0" waittime="7365" ownerId="2047519827" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2018-07-31T06:16:10.353" XDES="0x17db223920" lockMode="S" schedulerid="27" kpid="9788" status="suspended" spid="128" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2018-07-31T06:16:10.353" lastbatchcompleted="2018-07-31T06:16:10.303" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.303" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="abc_Server" hostpid="123" loginname="XYZ\SVC_ABC" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2047519827" currentdb="19" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="7018" stmtend="47282" sqlhandle="0x0200000045a5451b6c3d47c0d921b0f2f2ca56ca9a4b26fa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 bigint,@P3 bigint,@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5 bigint,@P6 bigint,@P7 nvarchar(4000),@P8 bigint,@P9 bigint,@P10 nvarchar(4000),@P11 bigint,@P12 bigint,@P13 nvarchar(4000),@P14 bigint,@P15 bigint,@P16 int,@P17 int,@P18 nvarchar(4000),@P19 bigint,@P20 bigint,@P21 nvarchar(4000),@P22 bigint,@P23 bigint,@P24 nvarchar(4000),@P25 bigint,@P26 bigint,@P27 nvarchar(4000),@P28 bigint,@P29 bigint,@P30 decimal(38,0),@P31 decimal(38,1),@P32 int,@P33 int,@P34 int,@P35 int,@P36 decimal(38,1),@P37 int,@P38 int,@P39 decimal(38,0),@P40 int,@P41 int,@P42 nvarchar(4000),@P43 bigint,@P44 bigint,@P45 nvarchar(4000),@P46 bigint,@P47 bigint,@P48 nvarchar(4000),@P49 bigint,@P50 bigint,@P51 nvarchar(4000),@P52 bigint,@P53 bigint,@P54 nvarchar(4000),@P55 bigint,@P56 bigint,@P57 nvarchar(4000),@P58 bigint,@P59 bigint,@P60 nvarchar(4000),@P61 bit,@P62 int,@P63 decimal(38,0),@P64 decimal(38,0),@P65 decimal(38,0),@P66 decimal(38,0),@P67 decimal(38,0),@P68 decimal(38,0),@P69 decimal(38,0),@P70 nvarchar(4   </inputbuf>
  </process>
  <process id="processa4d92f848" taskpriority="0" logused="2176492" waitresource="KEY: 19:72057594649706496 (e37a97d3049b)" waittime="7773" ownerId="2047625413" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-07-31T06:30:05.207" XDES="0x11bd931bf0" lockMode="X" schedulerid="7" kpid="13108" status="suspended" spid="121" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-07-31T06:30:05.207" lastbatchcompleted="2018-07-31T06:30:05.207" lastattention="2018-07-31T04:28:01.577" clientapp="jTDS" hostname="abc_Server" hostpid="123" loginname="XYZ\SVC_ABC" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2047625413" currentdb="19" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
   <executionStack>
    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="84" stmtend="412" sqlhandle="0x020000006f180e1fffe8b18ae2942c8e9498c66bdd56e2600000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
   </executionStack>
   <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 bigint,@P2 bigint)DELETE TOP(100000) FROM DIL2_OBJECT_NAME_88888888888888 WHERE rowStatus =  @P0  OR (expirationDate &gt;  @P1  AND expirationDate &lt;  @P2 )   </inputbuf>
  </process>
 </process-list>
 <resource-list>
  <ridlock fileid="1" pageid="6635214" dbid="19" objectname="Cache.dbo.DIL2_OBJECT_NAME_88888888888888" id="lock21441c4400" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594616020992">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processa4d92f848" mode="X" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processa4c4804e8" mode="S" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </ridlock>
  <keylock hobtid="72057594649706496" dbid="19" objectname="Cache6.dbo.DIL2_OBJECT_NAME_88888888888888" indexname="idx_" id="lock156e38f280" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594649706496">
   <owner-list>
    <owner id="processa4c4804e8" mode="S" />
   </owner-list>
   <waiter-list>
    <waiter id="processa4d92f848" mode="X" requestType="wait" />
   </waiter-list>
  </keylock>
 </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: @PaulWhite Done. Thanks for sending the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how did the select query (spid 128, on the left) is able to acquire a S (shared) lock on Index but not on the row?

An nonclustered index is a separate object from the table.  So the reader using the index first gets an S lock on the index key, and then retrieves the row locator (here a RID) from the leaf level of the index. To read the row referred to by the row locator will require an additional lock on the RID or the clustered index key.

> how did Delete query (SPID 121, on the right) is able to get X (exclusive) lock on object but unable to get a X lock on Index?

Similarly a query operating on the table (here a heap) gets an X lock on the RID to delete the row, and then needs to get an X lock on the corresponding index keys in the non-clustered indexes. But here the index key is locked by the reader. If you look at the DELETE query plan it's probably performing a table scan of the heap to find the rows to delete.

So this is a garden-variety reader/writer deadlock that would be avoided by having the readers use [Row Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2017#Row_versioning) (SNAPSHOT isolation, or setting the database in READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT mode), instead of using Shared Locks (S) to ensure a consistent view of the database.

As this appears to be a Denodo cache table, and deadlocks are application bugs, you may need to open a case with the vendor about a fix, and ask whether they support using Row Versioning for the cache tables.  I'd be disappointed in them if they don't.